# Algebra simplification

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm solving a reduction integral question. 
I'm stuck $x^2(1+x^2)^{n-1}$. I saw the solution it simplified to $(1+x^2)^n-(1+x^2)^{n-1}$.

I want to ask how it's done, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Factor out:

$$(1+x^2)^n-(1+x^2)^{n-1}=\left[1+x^2-1\right](1+x^2)^{n-1}=x^2(1+x^2)^{n-1}$$

You can go from left to right or the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2(1+x^2)^{n-1} = (1+x^2-1)(1+x^2)^{n-1} = (1+x^2)^n-(1+x^2)^{n-1}$$

Comment: I still couldn't get it from the second step to third :(

Comment: @Mathxx $(a-b)c = ac-bc$

Comment: @Mathxx Sure that's why my word "Hint" out there, $(1+x^2-1)(1+x^2)^{n-1} = (1+x^2)(1+x^2)^{n-1}  - (1+x^2)^{n-1} $ by strongest and biggest law of associativity, $(1+x^2)(1+x^2)^{n-1}=(1+x^2)^n $ then $ (1+x^2)(1+x^2)^{n-1}  - (1+x^2)^{n-1} =  (1+x^2)^n - (1+x^2)^{n-1}$

Comment: This is more than a hint...

Comment: @arthur yep in order to eradicate op's confusion

Comment: Then why call it a hint, when it's basically a full solution? A hint would be "$x^2=1+x^2-1$".

Comment: @arthur if i wrote this, it will be far beyond op's potential.

Comment: That is true, and I agree. I was not saying that you said too much. I was saying that it's wrong to call what you've written a hint.

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+x^2)^n-(1+x^2)^{n-1}=(1+x^2)(1+x^2)^{n-1}-(1+x^2)^{n-1}=(1+x^2-1)(1+x^2)^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2(1+x^2)^{n-1} = (x^2+1-1)(1+x^2)^{n-1}=({(x^2+1)}-1)(1+x^2)^{n-1}=\dots$$

Can you take it from here?